# Date is being removed on change of status

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to track when tasks are started & completed. I want to auto set the date depending on when the status of the task has changed. This is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save/task")
public String addTask(@ModelAttribute(value="task")Task task){
    Task taskBeforeUpdate=taskRepository.findById(task.getId());
    task.setTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    if ((taskBeforeUpdate.getCompletedDate()==null) && (taskBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress")) &&(task.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("completed"))){
        task.setCompletedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
    else if ((taskBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equals("New, Not Yet Started") ) && (task.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress"))){
        task.setInProgressDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return "redirect:/client/tasks/"+task.getClient().getId();
}
```

Say the task was "In Progress" and there was an in progress date that was set when it was originally set to that, when I change to "Completed" the In Progress Date then changes to NULL. I want to keep the in progress date in my sql database. How can I keep it from automatically removing that date when the status is changed?

This fixes the issue, but then causes other issues for other fields not "swapped":

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/save/task")
    public String addTask(@ModelAttribute(value="task")Task task){
        Task taskBeforeUpdate=taskRepository.findById(task.getId());
        task.setTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        if ((taskBeforeUpdate.getCompletedDate()==null) && (taskBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress")) &&(task.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("completed"))){
            task.setCompletedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            taskBeforeUpdate.setCompletedDate(task.getCompletedDate());
            taskBeforeUpdate.setStatus(task.getStatus());
        }
        else if ((taskBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("New, Not Yet Started") ) && (task.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("In Progress"))){
            task.setInProgressDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            taskBeforeUpdate.setInProgressDate(task.getInProgressDate());
            taskBeforeUpdate.setStatus(task.getStatus());
        }else{
           taskRepository.save(task);
        }
        taskRepository.save(taskBeforeUpdate);
        return "redirect:/client/tasks/"+task.getClient().getId();
    }
```

Comment: Reverse the logic. `taskBeforeUpdate` has all the current values, while `task` only has values for the fields that were sent from the client, so copy new values from `task` to `taskBeforeUpdate`, then use `taskBeforeUpdate` in the call to `save()`.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code to show the solution.

Comment: @Andreas this seems like a lot of code, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have the choice of copying values to be updated from the parameter object to the object read from the database, *or* copying the values not supplied in the parameter object from the database object to retain them. Copying from parameter is a lot less error-prone, especially if more fields get added later.

Comment: @Andreas so with the new code, it is removing a field that is only set in the beginning  when task is first created, is that because I have to reset that here and also its happening because I am doing the second way you described?

Answer (score 1):

The task that you are getting from DB ‘taskBeforeUpdate’ has all the values, while the parameter ‘task’ has only values coming from the client. You should copy new values from task to taskBeforeUpdate and then save taskBeforeUpdate in the database.

Comment: There are many other fields in a task, that now if those are updated, are not being saved due to saving taskBeforeUpdate. Is there a better way to do this? Otherwise I'd have to list each one in each if/else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

As Aman Garg said, you need to copy the new values to the old one and save only the old one. In your solution, I could see that you are saving task (in the else block) and then taskBeforeUpdate, which is not required at all and can create problems.